# Change wxWidgets LogLevel

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm failing to change the LogLevel of the wxLog functionalities.

What I would like to achieve: Log everything to a log-file.

In the following sample code logging basically works, but I see only messages with a LogLevel of `Warning` or `Error`. I thought that settting a logLevel using `wxLog::SetLogLevel(wxLOG_Info);` should be enough, but obviously I'm missing something. Any hints?

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
#include <wx/stdpaths.h>

class TestApp : public wxApp
{
public:

    virtual bool OnInit();

private:

    FILE* m_pLogFile;
};


bool TestApp::OnInit()
{
    m_pLogFile = fopen("c:\\tmp\\foo.txt", "a+");
    if (m_pLogFile == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    wxLogStderr* pFileLogger = new wxLogStderr(m_pLogFile);
    delete wxLog::SetActiveTarget(pFileLogger);

    wxLog::SetLogLevel(wxLOG_Info);

    wxLogError(L"Error");
    wxLogWarning(L"Warning");
    wxLogInfo(L"Info");
    wxLogVerbose(L"Verbose");
    wxLogDebug(L"Debug");

    wxFrame* pFrame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, L"Title");
    pFrame->Show();

    return true;
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(TestApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to unfortunate historical reasons `wxLogInfo()` is actually exactly the same as `wxLogVerbose()` and for equally unfortunate backwards compatibility reasons, verbose logging must be enabled by explicitly calling `wxLog::SetVerbose(true)`, so without it neither "Info" nor "Verbose" are logged (and with it both would be).

Actually we probably should finally fix this in wxWidgets 3.2, so hopefully it won't work like this in the next version. But for now you need to call `SetVerbose()` to enable these messages *in addition* to setting the log level.

Comment: Also see [this commit](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/da7388c9c8f875c4136b79c547e7663fe9bc41f7)